# Schatten $p$-classes for small $p$

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, operator-theory

Suppose $\mathcal H$ is a separable Hilbert space and $T$ is a compact self-adjoint operator on $\mathcal H$. Let $\{e_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal H$.
Fix $1<p<2$.

Does $T\in$Schatten p-class imply that $\displaystyle\sum_{m,n}|\langle Te_n,e_m\rangle|^p<+\infty$?

Comment: $Te_n$ can be anything, and in particular it can have arbitrary $\ell^2$ expansion coefficients wrt $\{ e_m\}$, so there's no reason for the sum (over just $m$) to be finite for $p<2$.

Comment: If I remember correctly, from a paper of Kehe Zhu, for $p>2$ this implication holds. But usually the case $p\in(1,2]$ is different.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_n|\langle Te_n,f_n\rangle|<\infty$ for any two ONB $(e_n)$, $(f_n)$?

Comment: No its a double-sum over an ONB namely $\displaystyle\sum_{m,n}|\langle Te_n,e_m\rangle|^p<+\infty$

Comment: @ChristianRemling I've just noticed that the OP is restricting attention to the case where $T$ is self-adjoint, so I think you would need a bit more work to get a counterexample than in your comment

Comment: @YemonChoi: This is no problem at all: Take a rank one $A=\langle e_1, \cdot \rangle f$ as above, with $f$ chosen such that $\sum |\langle f, e_m\rangle |^p=\infty$, and let $T=A+A^*$ (this won't mess up the divergence because $R(A)=L(e_1)$).

Comment: Or prove a simple lemma that for any two vectors $x,y\in H$, there's a self-adjoint rank $2$ operator $T$ with $Tx=y$ (well, I guess $x\not= 0$ to be safe). (It should be $R(A^*)$ above, if I could still edit...)

Comment: Could you provide the precise reference where the implication holds for $p\geq 2$? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an elaboration of Christian Remling's comment above.
The answer is no. Not even for a finite rank operator. Take $\cal H$ to be $l^2({\mathbb N})$ and choose any sequence $(a_n)$ in $l^2({\mathbb N})$ which is not in $l^p({\mathbb N})$. Let $(e_n)$ be the usual standard ONB. Let $T(e_1)=(a_n)$ and $T(e_j)=0$ for $j>1$. This operator has rank one. But
$$
\sum_{n,m}|\langle Te_n,e_m\rangle|^p=\sum_{m}|a_m|^p=\infty.
$$

Comment: Isn't this exactly my comment from above?

Comment: @ChristianRemling: yes, of course, but as the proposer didn't react, even answered to my question, I figured he might not have understood, so I expanded the answer. Besides, maybe he didn't take it, since it was not formulated as an answer, but as a doubt.

Comment: See my comment above: $T$ is assumed to be self-adjoint

Comment: It seem self-adjointness can be resolved by considering $\sqrt{T^*T}$, instead of $T$ in Corbennick's example. unless I'm missing something in here.

Comment: @BigM: yes, or $T+T^*$.